# Any difference between vector and array in memory layout of LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I have an array and a vector, and both of them hold the same data, like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
Then I use GEP to get the ptr of array,

```
%0 = getelementptr [5 x i32]* %arr, i32 0, i32 3
%1 = load i32* %0
```

so, %0 is the pointer of the 4th element in the array pointed by %arr, and the value of %1 is 3.

But now, I bitcast the pointer to the vector into a pointer to i32:

```
%2 = bitcast <5 x i32>* %Vec to i32*
```

and:

```
%3 = getelementptr i32* %2, i32 3
%4 = load i32* %3
```

I don't know exactly if there is any difference of the layout in the memory between array and vector.
If there is no difference, I think that way to get the element from a vector is ok.
So, am I on the right way to do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `bitcast` followed by a `gep` to get the 4th item in a vector, but it's redundant - you can just use a `gep` by itself, in exactly the same way as you have done with the array.

When using `gep`, you don't need to know anything about the memory layouts. In any case the memory for vectors is always laid out sequentially, as can be inferred from how `bitcast` behaves between vectors and integers; and since you can't `bitcast` arrays, their memory layout is immaterial.

Comment: So, the way I got is redundant but Ok, right? The document of llvm said that GEP is only for an *aggregate* data structure. But "vector" is not aggregete. See http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aggregate-types.

Comment: @gongweixue you are right, but continue reading and you could see "The first type indexed into must be a pointer value, subsequent types can be arrays, *vectors*, and structs." (plus there are examples with vectors down below). There's certainly nothing wrong with your bitcast - in fact, since a bitcast is typically a nop in the target language, the output will probably be identical - but a bitcast followed by a gep is less optimization-friendly than just a gep.

Comment: But I think the case down below means:get 4 element ptrs from each dim of vector by each index.It's not "get 4 element ptrs from a vector". It just dose GEP 4 times, is it?

Comment: @gongweixue I was referring to the 2nd code line on the larger example block: `%vptr = getelementptr {i32, <2 x i8>}* %svptr, i64 0, i32 1, i32 1` - the final `i32 1` indexes into the vector.

Answer (score 3):

According to "The Often Misunderstood GEP Instruction" (http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html) question "Can GEP index into vector elements?", "This hasn’t always been forcefully disallowed, though it’s not recommended. It leads to awkward special cases in the optimizers, and fundamental inconsistency in the IR. In the future, it will probably be outright disallowed."

So it's probably not a good idea to use GEP against vectors, but it's doable.

And in http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SequentialType.html, it says "All of these represent "arrays" in memory. The array type represents a specifically sized array, pointer types are unsized/unknown size arrays, vector types represent specifically sized arrays that allow for use of SIMD instructions. "

So it's better to decide whether or not vector is desired. If it does be the case, then 'extractelement' instruction is probably better (http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractelement-instruction).

Comment: Is a certain vector element in memory at a byte boundary, at all? E.g. in a <5 x i3> vector?